# Partial border with iOs on Ionic app

Tags: ios, css, ionic2, ionic3

At my company, we're making an Ionic3 app. In one of the pages, we show rankings in several tabs (each tab, shows a different ranking), and the way we're showing the active tab, is by setting a different `border-bottom` for the active tab title.

This works perfectly on Android devices, but on iOs devices, if a part of the tab title goes off screen (it has `overflow-x: scroll;` property set), that part doesn't get the border when scrolled. Better explained with an image:

[image]

I've tried looking on forums and stack, but I haven't seen anyone with the same problem or similar. Any idea?

Just in case, here's the code of the view:

```
<back-button></back-button>

<ion-content>

    <login-image></login-image>

    <div>
        <h1>{{'LOGIN.TITLE' | translate }}</h1>
        <h2>{{'LOGIN.SUBTITLE' | translate}}</h2>
    </div>

  <form class="form" [formGroup]="loginForm">

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>
        <ion-icon name="ios-mail-outline"></ion-icon>
      </ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" autocapitalize="off" formControlName="mail" placeholder="{{ 'LOGIN.MAIL' | translate }}"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>
        <ion-icon name="key"></ion-icon>
      </ion-label>
      <ion-input type="{{visible? 'text' : 'password'}}" formControlName="password" placeholder="{{'LOGIN.PASSWORD' | translate}}"></ion-input>
      <span class="eyeButton" item-right (click)="changeVisibility()">
        <ion-icon name="{{visible? 'eye': 'eye-off'}}"></ion-icon>
      </span>
    </ion-item>

    <div class="terms">
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="termsAccepted">
        <span class="slider"></span>
      </label>

      <p (click)="showTerms()" [innerHtml]="'REGISTRATION.TERMS' | translate "></p>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <a class="passLink" (click)="goToChangePass()" track-event [event]="'loginpage_gotochangepass'">{{'LOGIN.PASSLINK' | translate}}</a>
      <button (click)="doLogin(loginForm)" [ngClass]="{'disabled': loginForm.invalid}" class="formButton" type="button" track-event [event]="'loginpage_dologin'">{{'LOGIN.NEXT' | translate}}</button>
    </div>

  </form>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: do some coding based on platform , You should do this by ur own . check platform ios classes and then use  code inside that.

Comment: do you use ion-header for the header?

Comment: @jorghe94 actually, we don't use ion-header at all. I've added the code for said view, in case it helps (back-button is a component to add the FB button for going back on the top-left)

Comment: can you try to use ion-header? this have configurations for android and ios screens in relation to the notification bar, and aditionaly you can configure the buttons (left/back and right) of this. I've added a answer for you take a example

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ionic ion header directive, for example

```
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-navbar no-border>
    <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button>
        Left
      </button>
    <ion-buttons>
      <ion-title></ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button>
        Right
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

This have configurations for android and ios screens

I hope this helps you